# Can't identify which server is primary and which is secondary in a SQL Server Availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I'm writing an application that queries the backup history for a number of databases on a number of SQL Server 2017 servers.

Assuming a pair of servers (SQL001 and SQL002) and a database called "foo", how can I write a SQL query to tell me which server is the primary and which server is the secondary in the availability group?

Answer (score 2):

Use [sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-hadr-is-primary-replica-transact-sql). - [Sean Gallardy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/41723/sean-gallardy-mostly-retired)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could approach this is to utilise the function [`DATABASEPROPERTYEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with the property 'Updateability'.

For example:

```
DECLARE @STATE VARCHAR(100);
SET @STATE = (select CAST(DATABASEPROPERTYEX('foo', 'Updateability') as varchar(100)));        

IF(@STATE)  <> 'READ_ONLY'
    BEGIN
        Select @@servername as [ServerName]
    End;
```